# Android and SFMC Templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, css, content-builder

I'm using one of the Empty Templates to start. I then added a header and footer for a Base template. Everything is rendering fine, except for Android. Android phones are rendering the Desktop view not the Mobile (media query) view.

What am I missing? Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you post some code so we can help identify the issue please?

Answer (score 1):

All 'Native' android clients from 5.0 and up do not support media queries ([ref1](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/5243-android-5-1-native-email-app), [ref2](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6149-android-6-0-media-queries-column-stacking))

As stated in ref2(Litmus Blog, Jaina Mistry):

> Vendors who have their own default mail app (Samsung and Sony to name a couple) use the open source mail app from Google and often apply changes to it. Some of those changes can affect how the email is rendered.
>
> Android's complicated and incredibly fragmented—not just versions of the operating system in the wild but also screen sizes which have an impact on how emails render.

That being said, Gmail, which is the majority in a minority market share, DOES support media queries. This means that it will be a small majority that see the desktop version on mobile.

At that point you need to decide if it is worth it to template out using the '[hybrid](https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-responsive-and-hybrid-email-design)' approach (no longer using SFMC default templates) or if it is ok to lessen User Experience for those on Android (who likely are already used to receiving emails like this) by having the full size email display for them.